# Find Site template button in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, button, installation, task, sharepoint-2013

I wanted to download and install some Task lists from Microsoft and I can't find the button Site templates that are supposed to be under Galleries after you chose site settings. Do someone know how to make the button visible? I'm using SharePoint 2013 Standard edition.

Here is the link to the installation of the Task templates that I am trying to install:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24452

Comment: The download link you have provided is to get the WSS3.0 templates. Why do you need to use template that were designed for product 6 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are normally uploaded to your top level site and not arbitrarily to subsites.

If you are trying to add the templates make sure you're on your top level site and you should find the templates links there.

Regards
~Donald